# Multiple Screens in Python Using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm creating a game using the GUI Turtle in Python, and I want to have a "start" screen and a "you win" screen separate from the game screen itself. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several possible ways to do this:

1) Rather than full screens, you could pop up dialogs using:

```
turtle.textinput(title, prompt)
turtle.numinput(title, prompt, default=None, minval=None, maxval=None)
```

Although these are input dialogs, the `"You win!"` titled dialog window could include a `"Do you want to play again?"` prompt.

---

2) Between the "start" screen and the main program, and between the main program and the "You win!" screen you could do:

```
turtle.resetscreen()
```

To reset everything on the screen to an initial state and (re)draw what you need.

---

3) You import run both the **turtle** module and the **tkinter** module upon which it's built which allows multiple windows.  The "start" and "You win!" windows would likely need to be defined in terms of tkinter commands, rather than turtle, but the main window could still be turtle.

This is tricky to do.  Eg. you need to start it up carefully to make sure there is only one main window.  Do an SO search on the combined tags: [turtle-graphics] [tkinter] to get insight how to do this.